# Is there any way to avoid cartesian join in sql plus

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have three tables that are given below:

```
supplied_items(SUPPLIER_ID,ITEM_ID,QUANTITY,COST_PRICE);
ORDERS(ORDER_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,ITEM_ID,PRICE,QUANTITY,TOTAL_PRICE,ODATE);
EXPENSES(EXPENSE_ID,EDATE,DESCRIPTION,PAYMENT_TYPE,AMOUNT);
```

I have to calculate Net Profit. But when i include expenses table in query it make cartesian product with the rows of other tables.
Below are my queries:

```
SELECT
    SUM(orders.quantity * orders.price) AS "Sale",
    SUM(orders.quantity * supplied_items.cost_price) AS "COST",
    SUM(orders.quantity *(orders.price - supplied_items.cost_price)) AS "Profit",
    SUM(expenses.amount)
FROM
    orders
    LEFT OUTER JOIN supplied_items ON orders.item_id = supplied_items.item_id
    CROSS JOIN expenses;
```

Comment: You need a common column in `expenses` table with the other tables in order to get rid of cross join, or you might group by some column(s) along with keeping cross join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function Cause:
>
> A SELECT list
> cannot include both a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN,
> SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, and an individual column expression, unless
> the individual column expression is included in a GROUP BY clause.

That means without using proper group by clause you cannot use an aggregate function on a column along with a column without aggregation in oracle.

You cannot use `select a,sum(b) from table1` or `select sum(b),(select sum(a)from able1)from table1` for same reason.

You need to wrap the subquery with a group function like other columns. Please try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(orders.quantity * orders.price) AS "Sale",
    SUM(orders.quantity * supplied_items.cost_price) AS "COST",
    SUM(orders.quantity *(orders.price - supplied_items.cost_price)) AS "Profit",
    max(select SUM(expenses.amount) from expenses) expense_amount
FROM
    orders
    LEFT OUTER JOIN supplied_items ON orders.item_id = supplied_items.item_id;
```

Or you can also do this:

```
select Sale, COST, Profit,(select SUM(expenses.amount) from expenses) expense_amount
from
(SELECT
    SUM(orders.quantity * orders.price) AS "Sale",
    SUM(orders.quantity * supplied_items.cost_price) AS "COST",
    SUM(orders.quantity *(orders.price - supplied_items.cost_price)) AS "Profit",
    
FROM
    orders
    LEFT OUTER JOIN supplied_items ON orders.item_id = supplied_items.item_id;   
)t
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need the whole result of expense table:

```
SELECT
    SUM(orders.quantity * orders.price) AS "Sale",
    SUM(orders.quantity * supplied_items.cost_price) AS "COST",
    SUM(orders.quantity *(orders.price - supplied_items.cost_price)) AS "Profit",
    MAX(select SUM(expenses.amount) from expenses) as "Expenses"
FROM
    orders
    LEFT OUTER JOIN supplied_items ON orders.item_id = supplied_items.item_id
```

Comment: Yes you are right but in your query (select SUM(expenses.amount here SUM is not a single-group function and it creating an error.

Comment: not sure what you mean by that , that subquery returns one result and definitely works, give it a try

Comment: It gives error "ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"

Comment: @MuhammadAfnanAkram how about you wrap it with MAX() ? see updated asnwer